# What is the difference between the bcrypt() and the crypt() methods?

Tags: php, bcrypt, crypt

I was wondering what is the difference between these? I was having a discussion with someone about the crypt method and he was talking about the bcrypt method but to me it sounded like they are the same methods.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

crypt without arguments is the standard UNIX password hashing function ported to PHP whereas bcrypt is based on the Blowfish algorithm.

Bcrypt was designed specifically for hashing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses strong hash, generates strong salt, applies proper rounds automatically. `password_hash()` is simple `crypt()` wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes. Use of `password_hash()` is encouraged.

There is no `bcript` function in PHP.

Comment: bcript..? BTW great technique to end the question by changing the function names